# How to recover local files reset by git commands?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had accidentally reset a repository on my git account. The heads or commits (can't remember properly) were further from the local files. Now, the files in the local repository have vanished and synced with the git account repository. Is there any way we can recover those files?

When I pushed files into the bitbucket account, it always used to get stuck on 57%. I searched through the internet and found git repo reset codes. This caused all the files after the previous commit to disappear from the local repository. Now, I don't have those files on both local and git repositories.

Comment: We need more information in order to help you.  Were this missing files every committed prior to being lost?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Only the files that were not committed are lost. I also used recovery tools such as Recuva. They could only find the deleted files but not the lost ones.

Comment: If you really did a hard reset of your working directory and stage without committing or staging, then the files may be lost forever.  If your IDE or other type of code editing tool maintains a local history of files, you may try looking there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks man. I actually realized that the files might not have been deleted after I replied to your comment. So I tried git reflog show master, then I went for git checkout -b <new_branch> commit number, and finally git checkout <new_branch>. These commands recovered all my files to the desired commit.

Comment: I forgot to mention the git reset --hard <commit_number>

Comment: Glad you resolved your problem.  So in this case you _did_ already have the files committed.

Comment: Thank you very much.Yes because when I was pushing the files, it got stuck on 57% and then suddenly report a crash. I still have the same problem even if I create new repository.

Comment: If you get stuck on 57%, are your files very large? You might consider git-lfs instead of regular commits for large files. Second comment: since you solved your problem, can you post an answer saying what you did, and then mark it as solving the problem? This will allow others readers to see the problem is solved.

Comment: The files were not large. They were around 150 MB. I tried creating another repository in bitbucket and pushing it again. But the same problem had occured. So, I created a new account in Gitlab and pushed my files there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following codes should be able to solve such problems:

1. First use, `git reflog` to see all the commits.
2. Secondly, `git reset --hard <commit_number_from_reflog>`.
3. Then, `git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <commit_number>`.
4. Finally, `git checkout <new_branch_name>`.

These commands shall get your committed and unsaved files back.